# Importando dados tipo 1.000 (milhar) de html

Tags: r

Estou importando dados da base pública:

http://bolsafamilia.datasus.gov.br/w3c/consol_uf_cobertura_bfa.asp?gru=5&vigencia=34&vigatual=N&uf=SC&regional=00&regiaosaude=00&cob=1&brsm=1

com o seguinte código:

```
library(rvest)

for (i in 1:8){
    url_BF <- sprintf('http://bolsafamilia.datasus.gov.br/w3c/consol_uf_cobertura_bfa.asp?gru=5&vigencia=%02d&vigatual=N&uf=%02s&regional=00&regiaosaude=00&cob=1&brsm=1', 2*i+18,"SC")
    html_BF <- url_BF %>%
      httr::GET() %>%
      httr::content('text', encoding = 'latin1') %>%
      xml2::read_html() %>%
      rvest::html_nodes('table')

    data_BF <- html_BF[3] %>%
      html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
    data_BF <- as.data.frame(data_BF)

    if(i >= 1 & i < 5){
      linhas = c(294,295)
    }else if(i >= 5){
      linhas = c(296,297)
    }

    data_BF <- data_BF[-linhas,]
    data_BF <- data_BF %>% select(c(1,2,3,4))
    data_BF <- data_BF %>% mutate(ANO = 2009+i)

    if(i == 1){
    data_BF_ano <- data_BF  
    }else if(i > 1){
    data_BF_ano <- data_BF_ano %>% full_join(data_BF)
    }
}
```

Após extrair a tabela de interesse e transformá-la em `data.frame` o R está entendendo os valores numéricos "1.000" como decimais, todavia o ponto indica milhar de acordo à base de dados.

Como eu faço para ele entender que se trata de um milhar ou como eu posso remover o ponto sem alterar a estrutura dos dados?

Comment: Talvez `html_table(etc, dec = ",")` e depois `gsub("\\.", "", coluna_problema)` seguido de conversão com `as.numeric`.

Comment: Alterei a seguinte linha no código:
`data_BF <- html_BF[3] %>%  html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, dec = ",")`. E após o `data_BF <- as.data.frame(data_BF)` inclui as duas seguintes linhas:   `data_BF$Famílias.para.Acompanhamento <- as.numeric(gsub("\\.","",data_BF$Famílias.para.Acompanhamento))` e `data_BF$Famílias.Acompanhadas <- as.numeric(gsub("\\.","",data_BF$Famílias.Acompanhadas))`

Funcionou.
Obrigado @RuiBarradas